# csv.DictReader delimiter inside a csv field with multiple quotes

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have the following example csv, that I am reading with:

```
f = StringIO(response.encode('utf-8'))
reader = csv.DictReader(f, quotechar='"', delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, skipinitialspace=True)
```

example csv:

```
id;name;community;owner;owns;description;uuid
3c;NP;NoProb;NoP;Text;text_with_no_issues;
3c;NP;NoProb;NoP;TextText;text_with_no_issues2;
1A;fooo;barr;Bar;TEXT1;"\"text\"\"None\"\";text\"\"TEXT\"\"text\"";
1A;fooo;barr;Bar;TEXT2;"\"text\"\"None\"\";text\"\"TEXT\"\"text\"";
2B;BAR;foo;Bar;TEXT3;"\"text\"\"None\"\";text\"\"TEXT\"\"text\";text\"\"TEXT\"\"text\"";
2B;BAR;foo;Bar;TEXT4;"\"text\"\"None\"\";text\"\"TEXT\"\"text\";text\"\"TEXT\"\"text\"";
```

the uuid column is empty in all cases.
within the "reader" there are multiple entries with the same 'name' and 'id' which I am "merging", but in lines like the last four (1A,2B) I am hitting an issue because of the ";" delimiter in the description.

Even with quotechar='"' and quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL the description column gets spitted by the delimiter and goes to the next column (uuid) and to a "None" column which corrupts my data.

Any idea how to solve this one ?

P.S. for the merge logic I am using two variants:

```
##############################################################
    name_index = []
    result = []
    for line in reader:
        idx = line["name"]
        if idx not in name_index:
            name_index.append(idx)
            result.append(line)
        else:
            idx_curr_dict = result[name_index.index(idx)]
            merge_entries = [idx_curr_dict, line]
            placeholder = {}
            for key in idx_curr_dict:
                placeholder[key] = ", ".join(list(set(d[key] for d in merge_entries if d[key] != "" and d[key])))
            result[name_index.index(idx)] = placeholder
##############################################################
```

and a bit slower one, but not that complicated:

```
##############################################################
    data = [line for line in reply]  # Deplete the iterator
    unique_names = set([line['name'] for line in data])  # List of unique names
    column_names = [key for key in data[0] if key != 'name' and key != 'uuid']  # all other useful columns
    result = []
    for name in unique_names:
        same_named_lines = [line for line in data if line['name'] == name]
        unique_line = {'name': name}
        for column in column_names:
            value = ", ".join(set([line[column] for line in same_named_lines]))
            unique_line[column] = value
        result.append(unique_line)
##############################################################
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Having a delimited file in which any fields can contain the delimiter defeats the point of having a delimited file (as you're finding out).  Is there any way you can pre-process the file before reading it in?  So, for example, can you replace every occurrence of the string `\";` with `\":` (or something similar which doesn't contain a semi-colon character) before you try to apply the `csv.DictReader`?  This way, the *actual* delimiters should be left alone, and the pre-processed file should read in correctly.

Comment: Hi DatHydroGuy, it is a workable idea, thanks. The information is gathered from a database and there are not many entries with that kind of formatting.
I am trying to get more "flexible" and fast solution then pre-processing, that's why I went for quoting settings of the DictReader.